# Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS BCM4311 Wifi works, but no internet

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, xubuntu, broadcom

I have the original version of Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. But the same problem on any version of Linux. Notebook ACER Aspire 5310 (BCM4311)
Immediately after installation, I remove the drivers (sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source), download (using a VPN (PPTP) connection) and install firmware-b43-installer, otherwise my wifi does not work at all. I connect to it, but the Internet does not work. I connect from the phone to the same wifi and everything is in order. On win7 everything works fine.

- ping -c3 (ip) 0% pocket loss
- ping -c5 8.8.8.8 100% pocket loss
- sudo systemd-resolve --statistics - no cache
- rfkill list - no blocks

**ifconfig**

```
        ether 00:16:d4:e1:16:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11954  bytes 931482 (931.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11954  bytes 931482 (931.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 169.254.1.255
        inet6 fe80::23ed:d55:274d:7c4c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:19:7e:a6:2c:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1468  bytes 480118 (480.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48  bytes 7056 (7.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-LINK_43AE54"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 10:FE:ED:43:AE:54   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:45   Missed beacon:0

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

**cat ../network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1693] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [1025:012e]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [1468:0422]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

Comment: What ip do you ping there `ping -c3 (ip) 0% pocket loss`? And how did you install `firmware-b43-installer`? It is unclear what you mean by "download (using a VPN (PPTP) connection) and install firmware-b43-installer"

Comment: @Pilot6 my local ip - 169.254.1.1. I mean that i have installed firmware-b43-installer (download via pptp, sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer)

Comment: What do you mean by "download via pptp"? can you explain it? You can't simply download that package and install. And it is toatally unclear how pptp is involved.